# Implicit Broadcast Reciever isn't calling

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I searched the web for alot of time and I don't understand why my custom broadcast
isn't working.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".myservice.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I don't it not recieve when I reconnet and disconnect the charger.

I did this for making thing simpale

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
       Toast.makeText(context,"Battery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       Log.i("Recive", "Yes");
   }
}
```

Comment: Your logcat don't print Log.i("Recive", "Yes");? (filter logcat to show info message)

Comment: What device and Android version are you using?

Comment: It isn't printing and I am using oneplus 3t android 8

Comment: Which targetSdkVersion do you use? My answer works in Android 8 (Nexus 5X) with targetSdkVersion 25 or lower. Didn't test it with targetSdkVersion 26 or higher.

Comment: My phone is sdk 26

Comment: Not your phone, I'm talking about targetSdkVersion in your module `Gradle` file. Post your `Gradle`file please

Comment: minSdkVersion 21;
targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=es-419#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED):

> ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
>   Broadcast Action: This is a sticky broadcast containing the charging state, level, and other information about the battery. See BatteryManager for documentation on the contents of the Intent.
>
> You cannot receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver(). See ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY, ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED for distinct battery-related broadcasts that are sent and can be received through manifest receivers

So, you cannot use this `BroadcastReceiver` decalred in `Manifest`, only registering explicitly from your context.

Also, your power connection `BroadcastReceiver` seems correct. Try to separate it into another `BroadcastReceiver`, maybe action `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is interfering with other actions.

This is my declared `BroadcastReceiver` which I use and it's working in my app.

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class PowerConnectionBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String TAG = "PowerRcvr";
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Device is charging");
    } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED)) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Device is NOT charging");
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "Unable to check if device is charging or not");
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: This code is working on Android 8 with targetSdkVersion 25 or lower.

In targetSdkVersion 26 or higher most of `BroadcastReceivers` doesn't work through `Manifest` due to background limitations. Here are [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) (thanks to Pawel) about that. So your `IntentFilters` wont work. To keep it working you can download your targetSdkVersion to 25 or lower.

Comment: I think OP is trying to use this on android O, where implicit broadcasts don't work at all except some [exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions).

Comment: So I cant broadcasr a cable connection? there is another way? because I am using android O (26).

Comment: You can't broadcast BATTERY_CHANGED via Manifest (but you can do it manually programmatically via your Context). The cable connection can be declared in Manifest, and my code works fine in Android 8 but compiled with targetSdkVersion 25 or lower.

Comment: Can you explain me why it didn't work with targetSdkVersion 26+?

Comment: So, thanks to @Pawel there is why. Most of implicit `BroadcastReceivers` doesn't work with targetSdkVersion 26+ due to background limitations. Read this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.

Comment: So its limited because they didn't update all the brodcasts to 26?

Comment: It's limited because with targetSdkVersion 26+ the system optimization doesn't allow these kind of broadcasts being received. With targetSdkVersion 25 this optimization is not fired to your app.

Comment: Note that lowering targetSdkVersion is not a permanent solution - it will be a (long) while before that happens, but ultimately there will be android version where this optimization will be enforced regardless of targetSdk.